# Installing web.go errors

Tags: makefile, installation, go

I'm trying to install web.go. I got the source and ran make, but I'm getting these errors:

```
g -o _go_.6 cookie.go fcgi.go request.go scgi.go servefile.go status.go web.go 
cookie.go:33: c.Version undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Version)
cookie.go:34: c.Version undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Version)
cookie.go:54: c.Comment undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Comment)
cookie.go:55: c.Comment undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Comment)
cookie.go:78: c.Version undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Version)
cookie.go:79: c.Version undefined (type *http.Cookie has no field or method Version)
web.go:191: undefined: reflect.FuncValue
web.go:248: undefined: reflect.FuncValue
web.go:272: undefined: reflect.FuncType
web.go:591: undefined: reflect.FuncValue
cookie.go:79: too many errors
make: *** [_go_.6] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I just install go, so it should be the most recent version. 6g -V gives 6g version weekly.2011-04-04 8038.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've inadvertantly checked out past the latest weekly and brought in some recent changes to reflection. Try running

```
hg checkout -r weekly
```

Verify by running

```
hg identify
```

which should output

```
cd89452cfea3+ weekly/weekly.2011-04-04
```

Then run all.bash again to rebuild everything and try goinstalling web.go again.